# JOINing mdb tables with pyodbc

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I try to `JOIN` two MS access tables this way in python (pyodbc):

```
query = "SELECT Karta.id FROM Karta JOIN zaznam ON (Karta.id=zaznam.karta)"
cursor.execute(query)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError 42000  microsoft access driver syntax error in form clause -3506 SqlExecDirectW
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the type of join (`INNER`, `LEFT OUTER`, `RIGHT OUTER`) in the `FROM` clause. The type of join used depends on what you want the results to contain, I'm guessing you want an `INNER JOIN`. A reference for the join types available in Access can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243855%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

**Sample code assuming `INNER JOIN`**

```
query = "SELECT Karta.id FROM Karta INNER JOIN zaznam ON (Karta.id=zaznam.karta)"
cursor.execute(query)
```