# Creating a new Access table with pyodbc using SELECT ... INTO

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, pyodbc

I am trying to create a new table called Component_New, based on 3 different Access tables, and joined using common fields.

I currently have the following:

```
Make_Table = """ SELECT mapunit.mukey, copmgrp.cokey, copmgrp.copmgrpkey, copm.pmkind, copm.pmorigin, component.comppct_r, component.compname, component.majcompflag, copmgrp.pmgroupname INTO Component_Table FROM (mapunit INNER JOIN component ON (mapunit.mukey = component.mukey) INNER JOIN copmgrp ON (component.cokey = copmgrp.cokey) INNER JOIN copm ON (copmgrp.copmgrpkey = copm.copmgrpkey) INNER JOIN chorizon ON (component.cokey = chorizon.cokey)) """
cursor.execute(Make_Table)
con.commit()
```

Can't seem to find my mistake! 
Thank you in advance!

For a better understanding of my question: I simply want to know how to take the following add/joined information and create a table with it --> [JOINing mdb tables with pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700556/joining-mdb-tables-with-pyodbc)

The following code of mine works in Access, but I need to put it into Python so that I can loop through multiple different counties to do the same Add/Join:

```
SELECT mapunit.mukey, copmgrp.cokey, copmgrp.copmgrpkey, copm.pmkind, copm.pmorigin, component.comppct_r, component.compname, component.majcompflag, copmgrp.pmgroupname 
INTO Component_Table 
FROM (((mapunit INNER JOIN component ON mapunit.mukey = component.mukey) 
INNER JOIN copmgrp ON component.cokey = copmgrp.cokey) 
INNER JOIN copm ON copmgrp.copmgrpkey = copm.copmgrpkey) 
INNER JOIN chorizon ON component.cokey = chorizon.cokey;
```

Comment: Please use code format

Comment: I think it is in code format?

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses in your Python `Make_Table` string are not in the right places. In your Python script example you are (incorrectly) only putting the parentheses around the ON conditions

```sql
SELECT 
    mapunit.mukey, copmgrp.cokey, copmgrp.copmgrpkey, copm.pmkind, copm.pmorigin, component.comppct_r, component.compname, component.majcompflag, copmgrp.pmgroupname 
INTO Component_Table 
FROM 
    (
        mapunit 
        INNER JOIN 
        component 
            ON (mapunit.mukey = component.mukey) 
        INNER JOIN 
        copmgrp 
            ON (component.cokey = copmgrp.cokey) 
        INNER JOIN 
        copm 
            ON (copmgrp.copmgrpkey = copm.copmgrpkey) 
        INNER JOIN 
        chorizon 
            ON (component.cokey = chorizon.cokey)
    )
```

whereas in the subsequent example that works in Access you have the parentheses (correctly) around the whole INNER JOIN construct, as required by Access SQL

```sql
SELECT 
    mapunit.mukey, copmgrp.cokey, copmgrp.copmgrpkey, copm.pmkind, copm.pmorigin, component.comppct_r, component.compname, component.majcompflag, copmgrp.pmgroupname 
INTO Component_Table 
FROM 
    (
        (
            (
                mapunit 
                INNER JOIN 
                component 
                    ON mapunit.mukey = component.mukey
            ) 
            INNER JOIN 
            copmgrp 
                ON component.cokey = copmgrp.cokey
        ) 
        INNER JOIN 
        copm 
            ON copmgrp.copmgrpkey = copm.copmgrpkey
    ) 
    INNER JOIN 
    chorizon 
        ON component.cokey = chorizon.cokey
```

You need to adjust the SQL string in your Python code so the parentheses are in the right places.