# Pyodbc SQL SELECT Cursor.execute duplicating results

Tags: python, sql, select, pyodbc

```
 Records = Cursor.execute("SELECT cust_addr1, cust_addr2, cust_postcode, cust_telno_home, cust_email \
                           FROM tblcustomer, tblpet \
                           WHERE cust_surname = ? and tblpet.pet_deceased = ?" ,(SearchCriteria[0], "Y")).fetchall()
```

I can run this query if i remove the tblpet perfectly fine but when i add the tblpet the query runs but i get the results dupliated. So instead of 5 results i had something like 6300 but all of the same results looped.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have now fixed it thanks to **Mureinik** and **Siyual** for telling me about joins.
I then found these

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243855(v=office.12).aspx

[JOINing mdb tables with pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700556/joining-mdb-tables-with-pyodbc)

It worked 50% bu then i had a great idea of going into access and making the query then switching to SQL view and copying it. It works great and i was so so close

**ANSWER**

```
 Records = Cursor.execute("""SELECT tblcustomer.cust_addr1, tblcustomer.cust_addr2,
                             tblcustomer.cust_postcode, tblcustomer.cust_telno_home, tblcustomer.cust_email
                             FROM tblcustomer INNER JOIN tblpet ON (tblcustomer.cust_no = tblpet.pet_cust_no)
                             WHERE cust_surname = ? and tblpet.pet_deceased = ?""", (SearchCriteria[0],"Y")).fetchall()
```

Comment: Because this is doing a `CROSS JOIN`.  If you intend to `JOIN` the tables, use the explicit `JOIN` syntax (don't use commas in the `FROM` clause - [seriously, this was deprecated in 1992](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)) and show how the tables are related in the `ON` clause.

Comment: thank you - question updated

Answer (score 1):

When you write an implicit join like you did here (i.e., have more than one table in the `from` clause), the database creates a Cartesian product of the rows. You need to add a condition to match only the appropriate rows. E.g., assuming the customer has an ID and the pet has the ID of the customer:

```sql
SELECT cust_addr1, cust_addr2, cust_postcode, cust_telno_home, cust_email
FROM   tblcustomer, tblpet
WHERE  tblcustomer.id = tblpet.customer_id AND -- Here!
       cust_surname = ? AND
       tblpet.pet_deceased = ?
```

Or better yet, you can use the explicit `join` syntax:

```sql
SELECT cust_addr1, cust_addr2, cust_postcode, cust_telno_home, cust_email
FROM   tblcustomer
JOIN   tblpet ON tblcustomer.id = tblpet.customer_id -- Here!
WHERE  cust_surname = ? AND
       tblpet.pet_deceased = ?
```